# excel - "if" statement to exclude integers but include blanks & decimals

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a formula cell that will perform an operation based on qualifiers from other columns.

One such qualifier column contains integers, decimals, and blank cells.

I want to exclude the integers.

I have been unable to exclude integers without either excluding the decimals or the blanks along with it.

`If((Int(value) - value)=0)` isolates the integers and blanks from the decimals
`If(Int(value)>0)` isolates the integers and decimals from the blanks

I need something that will isolate the decimals and blanks from the integers

I can write this with two 'if-paths' but would rather not repeat the result for brevity

For Example: `If(Int(value)>0, If((Int(value) - value)=0, RESULT), RESULT)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A1),A1=0,A1="",INT(A1)-A1<0),"yes","no")
```

A1 is the value to test
Yes is the result for blanks and decimals
No the result for integers

In case you need to exclude 0 also use:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A1),A1="",INT(A1)-A1<0),"yes","no")
```

Or will be True if any of the following condition is True
ISBLANK(A1)
A1=0
A1=""
INT(A1)-A1<0)